# Get the number of exons and visualize them

Tags: r, bioconductor

I would like to ask you how can I get the number of exon? I want visualize gene length vs. number of exons in gene.

For example:

I have the length of the gene:

```
exons <- getBM(attributes = c("external_gene_name","start_position","end_position","ensembl_exon_id"),
          filters = "chromosome_name",
          values = "21",
          mart = genes)
exons[5] <- exons$end_position - exons$start_position
names(exons)[5] <- "gene_length"
```

I tried to find out the number of exons:

```
as.data.frame(table(exons$ensembl_exon_id))
```

But now, I don't know what else. Please, somebody would help me?

Comment: Please post `head(exons$ensembl_exon_id)`

Comment: head(exons$ensembl_exon_id)
[1] "ENSE00002088440" "ENSE00003722332" "ENSE00003716433" "ENSE00003729123" "ENSE00003739698" "ENSE00001809273"

Comment: If you want number of exons per transcript, then you need transcript ID (something like "ensembl_transcript_id) for each exon.

Comment: I want the number of exons per genes.

Comment: Same thing, you need `gene_id` for that